# Java filters, how to extend the filter?

Tags: java, lambda, filter, java-stream, predicates

Java streams' filters use `Predicate`s to allow or deny an element through the stream.

Thanks to `.compose` or `.andThen` the filter can be restricted.

Yet what if I wanted to have it more permissive according to some flags?

For example, I might want to have `isAppleAllowed` and `isPearAllowed` parametrically set by the user.

The use of `.filter(f -> isAppleAllowed || isPearAllowed)` doesn't work, because if either is True, both are allowed.

What can I use to extend the filter more permissively?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Your example doesn't make sense.  If `isAppleAllowed` and `isPearAllowed` are `boolean` parameters, as their names and your prose seem to indicate, then neither those individually nor any boolean combination of the two constitutes a predicate you can use for applying the filtering they describe.  You would instead want something along the lines of

```
fruitStream.filter(f -> { return f.isApple() && isAppleAllowed; })
```

to filter for apples, and similar for pears.  To filter jointly, you could use

```
fruitStream.filter(f -> {
    return (f.isApple() && isAppleAllowed)
            ||  (f.isPear() && isPearAllowed);
})
```

Alternatively, given two `Predicate<Fruit>` objects, say `applePredicate` and `pearPredicate`, class `Predicate` provides methods for forming joint predicates:

```
fruitStream.filter(applePredicate.or(pearPredicate))
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to change this answer, because what you're looking for was different than what I originally answered.  Using two separate calls to `Stream#filter`, as I previously suggested, wouldn't make sense, as both `Predicate`s would need to rely on each other in that case.

```
.filter(f -> (f.isApple() && isAppleAllowed) || (f.isPear() && isPearAllowed))
```

Something like this should work though, as it checks the attributes of the element before attempting to filter it.  Assuming the element can be either an apple or a pear, then it will be filtered through if `isAppleAllowed` or `isPearAllowed` is `true`, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an helper function that will return `Predicate` for you. Within this function, you can use both of your boolean function.